# Label every polygon in Geoserver multipolygon

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I want to label all areas in a multipolygon in Geoserver using SLD.
I have a map with two or three areas, but the label is only visible on the largest one. See attached images; the first image shows the map as a whole, the second image is zoomed in on the "northernmost part".

In Qgis there is a feature called *Label every part of multi-part features*. Is there something similar to this in Geoserver?

I've tried :

```
<VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">-1</VendorOption>
<VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
```

among other sld commands.

[image: The map]

[image: Zoomed in version]

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge (as the current maintainer of the GeoServer labeling engine) it cannot be done, unless you pre-process the data and split the above into multiple features.

An option to do that could be added though, like a `labelAllComponents` vendor option.

See this guide if you are interested in making it happen:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer